# Householding dilemna

Tags: households

I have been looking into a way to represent a B2C householding scenario in an org.

**Nonprofit Starter Pack**

I have come across the `Nonprofit Starter Pack -- Householding` package on the app exchange. It says it is free, and doesn't seem to imply that you have to be a nonprofit to use it? Just wondering if I am interpreting that correctly?

> The Nonprofit Starter Pack is a set of customizations to Salesforce.com CRM that supports some common nonprofit business processes. This package supports the grouping of people at the same address.

Not sure this is a good solution either way. As even in the demo, the `head of household` address changed and it didn't change the address on the household. Which, granted, could be debated if that is good or not. And yes, I am aware this is something we could easily take care of ourselves.

**Relationship Groups**

The other thing I came across was `Relationship Groups`, documented [here.](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/15/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_relgroups_getstart.pdf)

But in the documentation it says:

> Relationship groups are only available upon request to Salesforce for Wealth
>   Management customers. Note that the Relationship Groups tab may be named “Households”
>   in Salesforce for Wealth Management organizations. To enable relationship groups, contact
>   your Salesforce representative

We don't really need the `Wealth Management` solution. Buying a solution for one little piece we want out of it isn't going to work.

Looking for feedback from people that have ran into this need before and how they solved it.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct about not needing to be a nonprofit in order to use the NPSP. The paradigm used by the NPSP is totally different than traditional Salesforce one of Account first, then a contacts that are related to it. Households work very differently. With the NPSP, you create a contact first, then they get assigned to a Household (or one is created). That's why when you changed the address of a contact, the household's address didn't change. There can be a primary contact and many other contacts in the same household. They don't all need to have the same address. Some might be away at college or boarding school for example or want you to use their business address to contact them. Just like an Account, you edit the Household to make those kinds of changes.

Also, the complete package needs to be installed, not just the Householding package since some of the modules are interrelated (Relationships for example). You'll want to be aware that the NPSP basically takes Opportunity and uses that as a means of tracking Donations. There are many other nuances to it as well.

If you're thinking of trying to use it as a solution, you'll want to install it into a sandbox to see what it does to your data and what you'd need to do to make it work for you. You may find it's simply not a suitable solution for your particular business needs; that you'll want to create a custom solution of your own instead.

From having worked with it myself while standing up a number of nonprofit orgs, I wouldn't recommend it for business to customer use. I also would recommend you avoid implementing person accounts unless those are truly the ONLY kind of accounts you will be dealing with.

Recognize that you can always create a Record Type for Accounts that you could called "Household" with related contacts that belong to each Account of that Type. While that's a gross oversimplification, it's the essence of how Households work in the NPSP. There are other relationships as well which that doesn't take into account which the NPSP tracks.